# Add a disabled option item dynamically, using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just trying to create a separator for my select/option dropdown menu and am having trouble doing so.  i'm trying to create a dropdown that looks like this:

- NO IMAGE
- CUSTOM IMAGE

  ---
- rest of data....

I feel like what i'm doing should work but it's not... any help?

controller

```
$scope.teamListWithOptions.push({ name: "NO IMAGE" }, { name: "CUSTOM IMAGE" }, { name: "____________", notSelectable: true });

//this just adds the rest of the data
for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
  $scope.teamListWithOptions.push(data[a]);
}
```

html

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="contentTeam1Selected" ng-change="selectContentTeam1(contentTeam1Selected)" 
                                ng-options="team as team.name for team in teamListWithOptions" ng-disabled="team.notSelectable">
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a more recent version of angular *(>= 1.4 i think)*, you can use the `disable when` syntax inside the `ng-options` attribute. For example:

```
ng-option="p as p.name disable when p.show == false for p in people"
```

I have created an example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wwu071so/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `orderBy` to create an `optgroup` and get the effect you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/wwu071so/

```
<select
        ng-options="p as p.name group by p.show for p in people | orderBy:'show'"
        ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>

$scope.people = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Image' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Custom'},
    { id: 3, name: 'John', show: ' ' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Ben', show: ' ' }
];
$scope.selectedPerson = $scope.people[3];
```

Comment: hm i didn't really get your example.. it does put a seperator between Image/Custom and John/Ben, but not sure what that's supposed to do?  Thank you for the response tho!